# warning "using locale code page other than 65001 ("UTF-8") may cause problems" after R 4.2 update

Tags: r, encoding, utf-8

I work with multiple locales/languages  on Windows, and after my recent update to R 4.2, I keep seeing a warning "  using locale code page other than 65001 ("UTF-8") may cause problems" whenever I try to set the system locale (and regardless of what language I try to set it to).

When I revert back to R 4.1.3, the warning doesn't appear.

Can anyone tell me what this warning means and whether there's anyway to get rid of it? Thanks!

```
> Sys.setlocale("LC_ALL","English")
[1] "LC_COLLATE=English_United States.1252;LC_CTYPE=English_United States.1252;LC_MONETARY=English_United States.1252;LC_NUMERIC=C;LC_TIME=English_United States.1252"
Warning message:
In Sys.setlocale("LC_ALL", "English") :
  using locale code page other than 65001 ("UTF-8") may cause problems


> sessionInfo()
R version 4.2.0 (2022-04-22 ucrt)
Platform: x86_64-w64-mingw32/x64 (64-bit)
Running under: Windows 10 x64 (build 22000)

Matrix products: default

locale:
[1] LC_COLLATE=English_United States.1252 
[2] LC_CTYPE=English_United States.1252   
[3] LC_MONETARY=English_United States.1252
[4] LC_NUMERIC=C                          
[5] LC_TIME=English_United States.1252    
system code page: 65001

attached base packages:
[1] stats     graphics  grDevices utils     datasets  methods   base     

loaded via a namespace (and not attached):
 [1] fansi_1.0.3      assertthat_0.2.1 dplyr_1.0.9      utf8_1.2.2      
 [5] crayon_1.5.1     grid_4.2.0       R6_2.5.1         DBI_1.1.2       
 [9] lifecycle_1.0.1  gtable_0.3.0     magrittr_2.0.3   scales_1.2.0    
[13] ggplot2_3.3.6    pillar_1.7.0     rlang_1.0.2      cli_3.3.0       
[17] generics_0.1.2   vctrs_0.4.1      ellipsis_0.3.2   glue_1.6.2      
[21] purrr_0.3.4      munsell_0.5.0    compiler_4.2.0   pkgconfig_2.0.3 
[25] colorspace_2.0-3 tidyselect_1.1.2 tibble_3.1.7    
>
```

Comment: What's wrong on `Sys.setlocale("LC_ALL","English.utf8")`?

Comment: Thanks JosefZ! Running the code you suggest doesn't trigger the warning anymore!